# Importing shapefile in PostGIS DB

Tags: postgis, shapefile, sql

I am trying to import a shapefile (created using QGIS)

[image]

into my PostgreSQL DB with PostGIS extension using SQL. I got the message below, any body can help:

> Importing with configuration: transects, public, geom,
> C:\SQL\transects.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1,
> shape=1, srid=4326 Shapefile type: Arc PostGIS type:
> MULTILINESTRING[2] Shapefile import failed.

Comment: Ensure your SRID is correct. As an aside, I find that the import utility with PostGIS kind of spotty in the past, and that importing a layer through QGIS far more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created the database again and somehow worked. It must be something I missed when setting up the first database.